# How to transition between EditText and Spinner?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, xamarin

I have an Edittext wrapped inside a TextInputLayout. I tried using  **android:nextFocusForward="@+id/spinnerLanguage"** so that i could gain the focus of the spinner. This doesn't work. I even tried using android:nextFocusUp and this method does not seem to work

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/txtEmailAddressWrapper"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
          <EditText
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text=""
              android:hint="EMAIL ADDRESS"
              android:padding="5dp"
              android:id="@+id/txtEmailAddress"
              android:nextFocusForward="@+id/spinnerLanguage"
              android:inputType="text"
              android:maxLength="40" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <fr.ganfra.materialspinner.MaterialSpinner
            android:id="@+id/spinnerLanguage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:ms_floatingLabelColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:ms_enableFloatingLabel="true"
            app:ms_hint="LANGUAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
txtEmailAddress.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

or

```
txtEmailAddress.setFocusable(false);
```

and use this to clear focous

```
txtEmailAddress.clearFocus();
```

or use this in xml

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

may be this will help you